# How to cope with a class which implements Comparable<?> and not Comparable<E>?

Tags: java, generics

I have created an `Iterator` wrapper which returns elements until a certain threshold is reached as following:

```
public class MyIterators {
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> Iterator<E> threshold(final Iterator<? extends E> iterator, final E threshold) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to use this for an `Iterator<ChronoZonedDateTime>` in a utility function as following:

```
public static Iterator<ZonedDateTime> oneYear(final Iterator<ZonedDateTime> iterator) {
    return MyIterators.threshold(iterator, ZonedDateTime.now().plusYears(1));
}
```

I am getting:

```
method threshold in class MyIterators cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.util.Iterator<? extends E>,E
[ERROR]   found: java.util.Iterator<java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime>,java.time.ZonedDateTime
[ERROR]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
[ERROR]     (argument mismatch; java.util.Iterator<java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime> cannot be converted to java.util.Iterator<? extends java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime<?>>)
```

The compiler is inferring `ChronoZonedDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime`, while I am not declaring/using that class at all.

How do I cope with this? Do I introduce a manual cast, or is there still a way to do all this in a type-safe manner?

I am working with JDK 8.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is caused by the raw type, `ChronoZonedDateTime`. If you specify a wildcard for the generic type, `ChronoZonedDateTime<?>`, then your code compiles and runs:

```
final Iterator<ChronoZonedDateTime<?>> iterator = null;
MyIterators.threshold(iterator, ZonedDateTime.now().plusYears(1));
```

See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

Editing this answer as OP removed some information from the question.

Regarding your second problem, you should change `<E extends Comparable<E>>` to `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` in the signature of `threshold`, which will allow you to pass in `Iterator` objects whose generic type is one that compares against its parent type.

The new method signature should look like the following:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> Iterator<E> threshold(final Iterator<? extends E> iterator, final E threshold) {
```